# Use Kinect XBOX one with NIVIEWER

Tags: kinect, openni, xbox

I am really new to the whole Kinect world.

I have the XBox One Kinect with the Windows Adapter, have installed the last version of the Kinect SDK sucessfully and recorded some videos with the Kinect Studio v2.0 and got some .xef files, which I cannot use, since I need .oni files for a certain program. 
So I tried to record with the OpenNI 2's NIVIEWER program, but it does not recognize the Kinect. I tested the NIVIEWER with the ASUS xtion Pro and it did work. I even reinstalled  OPENNi2.2/NITE2/KINECT SDK but it still does not work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: OpenNI 2 does not support Kinect 2 natively, there is a branch for it though (https://github.com/occipital/OpenNI2/tree/kinect2/Source/Drivers/Kinect2). You can also try to compile and use the OpenNI 2 driver for Kinect 2 of https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2

Answer (score 1):

Kinect v2 and the kinect for xbox one, doesn't work with OpenNI directly. You have a couple of options:

1. Work with Kinect v1
2. Work with Kinect SDK only
3. Work with experimental drivers such as [this one](https://github.com/occipital/OpenNI2/tree/kinect2/Source/Drivers/Kinect2). Note that it only works in windows.
4. You may try to save the rgb and depth images and create the oni by any other means (I think this option is not that easy)

Hope this helps you